# Adding Amt1 and Amt2 values to the output column value of previous record

Tags: mysql

**Input:**

```
  dated    amount   Amt1    Amt2
1/1/2017    100      0      10
1/2/2017    100      10     0
1/4/2017    100      0      0
1/6/2017    100     300     10
1/10/2017   100     0       20
1/11/2017   100     350     650
1/12/2017   100     0       234
```

**Output**:

```
dated       amount  Amt1    Amt2    Output Column
1/1/2017    100     0       10      100
1/2/2017    100     10      0       110
1/4/2017    100     0       0       120
1/6/2017    100     300     10      120
1/10/2017   100     0       20      430
1/11/2017   100     350     650     450
1/12/2017   100     0       234     1450
```

Output column is calculated with adding Amt1 and Amt2 values to the Output Column value of previous record.

**Example:** Output Column of
first record is as it is of Amount column,
second record will get from first record value of output column and Amt1 and Amt2 of first record i.e 100+0+10=110,
third record is from 110+10+0=120
fourth record is from 120+0+0=120
fifth record is from 120+300+10=430 ...

Comment: mysql vesrion ??

Comment: You can do this easily if you use a spreadsheet program like Excel etc.

Comment: @tcadidot0 maybe so, but a suggestion like that on a forum like this is tantamount to heresy

Comment: I am puzzled by the role amount plays in this. I can see that you just carry it into output column for the first row but what happens if the amount value changes (if it does)?

Comment: @Strawberry , I'm not gonna argue with that. In that case, to OP, you should at least give us what you have tried so far. But before that, in my opinion, I think the way to achieve this will involve a lot of hard-coding..

Comment: @tcadidot0 in which case sit back, and prepare to be amazed

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples of how to calculate running totals on this site and here's one which uses a variable. I am concerned that the purpose of the amount column is not defined but this solution works with the data provided for installation with mysql lower than version 8 (it will work with version 8 or above but there are better ways of doing it there). @tcadidot0 no hard coding required.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(  dated date,   amount int,   Amt1 int,   Amt2 int);
insert into t values
(str_to_date('1/1/2017','%d/%m/%Y')   , 100  ,    0   ,   10),
(str_to_date('1/2/2017','%d/%m/%Y')   , 100  ,    10  ,   0),
(str_to_date('1/4/2017','%d/%m/%Y')   , 100  ,    0   ,   0),
(str_to_date('1/6/2017','%d/%m/%Y')   , 100  ,   300  ,   10),
(str_to_date('1/10/2017','%d/%m/%Y')  , 100  ,   0    ,   20),
(str_to_date('1/11/2017','%d/%m/%Y')  , 100  ,   350  ,   650),
(str_to_date('1/12/2017','%d/%m/%Y')  , 100  ,   0    ,   234);

select t.dated,t.amount,t.amt1,t.amt2, 
         if(t.dated = (select min(t1.dated) from t t1),@op:=amount,
         @op:=@op + 
         (select amt1 + amt2 from t t1 where t1.dated < t.dated order by t1.dated desc limit 1) 
         ) op
from t 
cross join (select @op:=0) o
order by dated;

+------------+--------+------+------+------+
| dated      | amount | amt1 | amt2 | op   |
+------------+--------+------+------+------+
| 2017-01-01 |    100 |    0 |   10 |  100 |
| 2017-02-01 |    100 |   10 |    0 |  110 |
| 2017-04-01 |    100 |    0 |    0 |  120 |
| 2017-06-01 |    100 |  300 |   10 |  120 |
| 2017-10-01 |    100 |    0 |   20 |  430 |
| 2017-11-01 |    100 |  350 |  650 |  450 |
| 2017-12-01 |    100 |    0 |  234 | 1450 |
+------------+--------+------+------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ok, you've clearly made my opinion wrong @P.Salmon ! I'm sorry for that. Anyway, I'm gonna learn this method and try to apply into our practice. Thanks XD

Comment: @tcadidot0 no need for apologies. You should also read up on window functions in version 8 - which are a much tidier way of doing this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html.

Comment: I will @P.Salmon but you know what, we've been trying to get our employer to change to version 8 because we know there are a lot of "nice" new functions compared to what we're still using now (the ancient 4.1!). But they're too afraid that our program won't function well with the new version. The closest we've got to use is Mariadb 10.3, but that's only on a few server. So, your solution here is much more meaningful to us at the moment ;)

Comment: please explain above query